# tikz text location within node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've looked around and surprisingly haven't found a clear answer to this question.  I have some boxes I'm drawing with tikz.  I would like the text (in this case `D`) for the `bigbox` boxes to be in the bottom right, without having to do anything to give any coordinates on a case by case basis.  Instead the text is appearing in the center of the box.  I don't seem to have control over that except through putting a lot of white space before the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings,shapes,arrows,fit}
\tikzstyle{box}=[draw, minimum size=2em, text width=4.5em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{bigbox}=[draw, inner sep=20pt]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (A) at ( -2,1) {$A$};
    \node[box] (B) at ( 1,1) {$B$};
    \node[box] (C) at ( 4,1) {$C$};
    \node[bigbox, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (D) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a label and then shift it to inside like

```
label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}
```

in the definition of `bigbox`:

```
bigbox/.style={draw, inner sep=20pt,label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}}
```

and then say `bigbox=D` in

```
\node[bigbox=D, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (D) {};
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings,shapes,arrows,fit}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum size=2em, text width=4.5em, text centered},
         bigbox/.style={draw, inner sep=20pt,label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (A) at ( -2,1) {$A$};
    \node[box] (B) at ( 1,1) {$B$};
    \node[box] (C) at ( 4,1) {$C$};
    \node[bigbox=D, fit=(A)(B)(C),] (D) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

Response to the comments:

Here a `label` is drawn for the node with `label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}` which is `shift`ed and `#1` is the content of the label. For more, refer to `pgfmanual`. As for the complex content, I hope the following is complex enough :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings,shapes,arrows,fit}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum size=2em, text width=4.5em, text centered},
         bigbox/.style={draw, inner sep=20pt,label={[align=right,shift={(-1.5ex,3ex)}]south east:\llap{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (A) at ( -2,1) {$A$};
    \node[box] (B) at ( 1,1) {$B$};
    \node[box] (C) at ( 4,1) {$C$};
    \node[bigbox={$x^n + y^n = z^n$},label=south east:D, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (D) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give a few more details about exactly what this `label={[shift={(-3ex,3ex)}]south east:#1}` is doing?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted the box to have a label D, but have the text showing be, $D_1^r$ --- that is I want a simpler label to use for references within the figure, but I want it to display a more complicated math formula?

Comment: @Joel Please see the edit.

Answer (score 4):

You could add an extra node for setting the `D` text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings,shapes,arrows,fit}
\tikzstyle{box}=[draw, minimum size=2em, text width=4.5em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{bigbox}=[draw, inner sep=20pt]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (A) at ( -2,1) {$A$};
    \node[box] (B) at ( 1,1) {$B$};
    \node[box] (C) at ( 4,1) {$C$};
    \node[bigbox, fit=(A)(B)(C)] (D) {};
    \node[above left] at (D.south east) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]