# revisiting tikz text location within node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm following the answer I got [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223820/tikz-text-location-within-node) for a previous question about how to control text location within a large node in `tikz`.  I would like a slanted box to surround 4 smaller boxes, and then automatically place the label for the slanted box in the top right.  It's not far enough right.  I could manually force it over, but I'll be doing this a number of times and the slanted box will change size each time.  So it would have to be done repeatedly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,backgrounds}

\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum width = 1.cm, minimum height = 1.cm, text width=1cm, text centered},
slantedbox/.style={draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70, label={[shift={(9ex,-3ex)}]north east:#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [box] (phiQQ) at (0,0) {$\phi_{QQ}$};
\node [box] (phiQA) at (3,0) {$\phi_{QA}$};
\node [box] (phiQ*A) at (6,0) {$\phi_{Q^*A}$};
\node [box] (phiAA) at (4.5,-2) {$\phi_{AA}$};
\node [slantedbox = $\xi$, fit = (phiQQ)(phiQA)(phiQ*A)(phiAA), minimum height = 2cm] at (3,-1) (xi) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's my current output:
[image]

I want the `$\xi$` farther right automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `top right corner` in

```
slantedbox/.style={draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,
          trapezium right angle=-70, label={[shift={(0,-3ex)}]top right corner:#1}}
```

The possible anchors are (from `pgfmanual` page 705)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,backgrounds}

\tikzset{box/.style={draw, minimum width = 1.cm, minimum height = 1.cm, text width=1cm, text centered},
slantedbox/.style={draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,
          trapezium right angle=-70, label={[shift={(0,-3ex)}]top right corner:#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [box] (phiQQ) at (0,0) {$\phi_{QQ}$};
\node [box] (phiQA) at (3,0) {$\phi_{QA}$};
\node [box] (phiQ*A) at (6,0) {$\phi_{Q^*A}$};
\node [box] (phiAA) at (4.5,-2) {$\phi_{AA}$};
\node [slantedbox = $\xi$, fit = (phiQQ)(phiQA)(phiQ*A)(phiAA), minimum height = 2cm] at (3,-1) (xi) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]